# Why have all Android TV remote apps stopped working?

Tags: remote-control, android-tv

As on date, nothing on play store can detect my Kogan TV running stock Android TV 9. The Google TV app is supposed to have a remote now, but it isn't shown for me. The system Android TV remote service on my TV is version 5.1+ (supposedly you need it to be > version 5).

None of the other remote apps can detect the TV over WiFi or Bluetooth - I see review ratings of 2 and 3 all over the place with the same complaint. Is there a fix or a working app or has Google intercoursed everybody as usual with one of their updates, given they apparently retired their standalone remote app for bundling it with the stupid Google TV app, which is bloatware if all you want is a remote (assuming the feature is available, which is isn't for me)?

If at all relevant, I'm using an ASUS ROG phone 5 with Android 12.

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes from an update of Android TV Remote Service. In this update they modified the whole communication protocol.

Here is my app, that works even with this update: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.niamor.androidtvremote

If you need, you can contact me by email directly from the app.
Thank you.

Comment: This was one of the apps I tried - fails to detect the TV over the same network and doesn't seem to let you manually specify the TV's address. The TV is connected to the router via LAN cable and successfully pings from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the reason the remote tv apps are not working is an update to the android remote tv service on the android tv device. Users are finding that uninstalling the update on the TV device and turning off auto updates seems to solve the problem.